# Error handling in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, error-handling

I've struggled a couple of days with the error handling in MVC. I still do not have got it right. (I've also read most of the questions here at SO and googled until my fingers bled)

What I want to do:

1. Use the standard `[Authorize]` attribute
2. Redirect all errors to my error controller (including unauthorized)
3. Have one action per HTTP error in my error controller.

What I do not want to do:

1. Put the `[ErrorHandler]` on all of my controllers (can it be used on my base controller)?
2. Use a custom Authorize attribute.

Actually I could do anything necessary (including the NOT list) as long as I get #1-3 working.

What I've tried:

1. Using `Application_Error`
2. Using `Controller.HandleUnknownAction`
3. Using `Controller.OnException`
4. Using `[ErrorHandler]` on my controllers
5. Turning on/off `CustomErrors` in web.config

Guess I need a combination of those or maybe something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom filter, just extend ErrorHandlerAttribute and make it aware of your error controller. Than add it as a global filter inside `Application_Start`:

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new CustomAErrorHandlerAttribute());
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also handle all your error logic in the `Application_Error` of your `Global.asax.cs` and then route them dynamically bases on the different HTTP status codes:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ex = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();

    var routeData = new RouteData();

    if (ex.GetType() == typeof(HttpException))
    {
        var httpException = (HttpException)ex;

        switch (httpException.GetHttpCode())
        {
            case 401:
                routeData.Values.Add("action", "NotAuthorized");
                break;
            case 403:
                routeData.Values.Add("action", "NotAuthorized");
                break;
            case 404:
                routeData.Values.Add("action", "PageNotFound");
                break;
            default:
                routeData.Values.Add("action", "GeneralError");
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        routeData.Values.Add("action", "GeneralError");
    }

    routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");
    routeData.Values.Add("error", ex);

    IController errorController = new ErrorController();
    errorController.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
}
```

It seems the `401` doesn't throw necessary a `HttpException` so you want to handle that manually to fit the logic:

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Context.Response.StatusCode == 401)
    {
        throw new HttpException(401, "You are not authorised");
    }
}
```

And yes, your controllers inherit the attributes from your base conroller.

Comment: Tried that. It doesn't get called for 401. I have no idea why.

Comment: Haven't tried that for a 401, but according to this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679881/asp-net-mvc-user-friendly-401-error) it should throw a `HttpException` as well.

Comment: Ah, it could be that you need to check for `Context.Response.StatusCode == 401` in your `Application_EndRequest()` and then throw the `HttpException(401, "You are not authorised")` by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is not to use `Application_Error`. The proper way is to use `[HandleError]` attribute in combination with the `customErrors` section in web.config as I describe here:

http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/11/how-to-handle-errors-in-asp-net-mvc/